# How to make sure one function get triggers after other function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a refresh function:

```
function refresh(nRefresh)
{
 TimerSetting = document.all.curRefresh.Timer;
 document.all.curRefresh.Timer = 'On';    
 nTimeOut = nRefresh;
 updateKnlButtons();
 psStatusUpdate();
}
```

This function reload the page.
After clicking on a button I give refresh(5) to refresh a page after 5 seconds. Due to some reason I want to fire a function after refresh function is completed, but this function is getting fired before refresh function is completed. How to make sure disable function is called after refresh function is completed?

```
function disableButton()
{
 idStopSelBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idStartSelBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idBounceRunningBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idStopAllBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idStartAllBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idBounceSelBtn.style.cursor='wait'
 idStopSelBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Stop-Selected.gif';
 idStartSelBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Start-Selected.gif';
 idBounceRunningBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Bounce-Running.gif';
 idStopAllBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Stop-All.gif';
 idBounceSelBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Bounce-Selected.gif'
 idStartAllBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Start-All.gif';
 idStopSelBtn.onclick="return false";
}
```

Comment: Where is `disableButton` called?  Where is a timer set?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand  Just after refresh function . The code is like 
refresh(5);
disableButton();

Comment: Why can't you add disableButton as the last line of refresh function?

Comment: @closure because refresh function is used several time in the same page and in every case disableButton() should not be fired ,but thanks you give me an idea. I will create new refresh function for that particular case with disableButton() at last .

Answer (score 2):

You may just add another parameter (`disable flag`) to achieve the desired result.

```
function refresh(nRefresh, disable) {
  TimerSetting = document.all.curRefresh.Timer;
  document.all.curRefresh.Timer = 'On';
  nTimeOut = nRefresh;
  updateKnlButtons();
  psStatusUpdate();
  if (disable) disableButton();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
function refresh(nRefresh, disableButton) {
  TimerSetting = document.all.curRefresh.Timer;
  document.all.curRefresh.Timer = 'On';    
  nTimeOut = nRefresh;
  updateKnlButtons();
  psStatusUpdate();
  disableButton();
}

function disableButton() {
  idStopSelBtn.style.cursor='wait';
  idStartSelBtn.style.cursor='wait';
  idBounceRunningBtn.style.cursor='wait';
  idStopAllBtn.style.cursor='wait';
  idStartAllBtn.style.cursor='wait';
  idBounceSelBtn.style.cursor='wait'
  idStopSelBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Stop-Selected.gif';
  idStartSelBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Start-Selected.gif';
  idBounceRunningBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Bounce-Running.gif';
  idStopAllBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Stop-All.gif';
  idBounceSelBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Bounce-Selected.gif'
  idStartAllBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Start-All.gif';
  idStopSelBtn.onclick="return false";
}

refresh(5, disableButton);
```